# Zookeeper client node did not reconnect after session expired

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I intercepted the connection between Zookeeper server and the client node using a custom TCP Monitor (Similar to TCPMon). I stopped the TCPMon and restarted it. When I restarted the TCPMon after the session expiration the client node is notified ("session has expired") but did not reconnect. How can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get session expired, you need to close the ZooKeeper handle and re-create it.

From [The Programmer's Guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkSessions) - "once a ZooKeeper object is closed or receives a fatal event (SESSION_EXPIRED and AUTH_FAILED), the ZooKeeper object becomes invalid"

Comment: What specifically does "closing the ZooKeeper handle and re-creating it" entail?  I'm using CloudSolrServer.  I would have guessed completely shutting down the JVM I'm running in for much longer than zkClientTimeout would have done the trick, but apparently it doesn't.  Calling `myServer.shutdown(); myServer = new CloudSolrServer("zkHost:12345"); myServer.connect();` doesn't seem to work either.